# Show whole lines while piping live logs to fzf

Tags: fzf

I'm trying to pipe logs to fzf so that I'll be able to filter them live, as my program spits a lot of logs out.

However, I've noticed the long lines get truncated and I have no way to show the whole lines, except to press `ENTER`, at which point the line will be displayed in it's entirety but the logs will be deleted from the screen and the program will crash with the error `failed printing to stdout: Broken pipe (os error 32)'`

It seems `fzf` supports this feature, as it has a `--no-hscroll: Disable horizontal scroll` flag, implying horizontal scroll is available by default, but arrow keys don't work, at least not alone or with the usual modifiers.

I've also tried using `less -S` for this, but doesn't work on live logs as it doesn't resume following after the first interrupt and `F` command.

As an alternative, I've noticed `fzf` supports a preview window feature, it would be neat to have the whole line display there so that the logs are still visible and scrolling while following the lines.

I could append logs to a file and try working from there, but is that necessary? Or can these tools also work properly on live `stdout` logs?

Comment: [It seems](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/461) it's not possible and won't be implemented any time soon